# TypeError in views/welcome.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a chat app, where i'm trying to save data like in this format

{"name": "luxii",
"chat": "blah blah",
"chat": "more blah"
}

so the code i've written is giving me following error.

```
TypeError: /home/admin/session/views/welcome.ejs:21
   19|    for(var j=0;j<data.name.length;j++){ %>
   20| 
>> 21| <%= data[i].name %>:<%=data.name[j].chat%>
   22| <%}}%>
   23| </class>
   24| <form class="form" method="post" action="/chat">

Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> 
(/home/admin/session/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:524:12), <anonymous>:16:33)
at returnedFn (/home/admin/session/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:555:17)
at tryHandleCache (/home/admin/session/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:203:34)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] 
(/home/admin/session/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:412:10)
at View.render (/home/admin/session/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:128:8)
at tryRender 
(/home/admin/session/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
at EventEmitter.render 
(/home/admin/session/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
at ServerResponse.render 
(/home/admin/session/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
at /home/admin/session/index.js:31:5
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
(/home/admin/session/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

my index.js file --

```
const express=require('express');
const ejs=require('ejs');
const cookieParser=require('cookie-parser');
const session=require('express-session');
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');

var app=express();


var data=[];
var usern;
var userp;
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.render(__dirname+'/views/index.ejs');
});

app.post('/sign',function(req,res){
usern=req.body.username ;
userp=req.body.password;

res.redirect('/welcome');
});


app.get('/welcome',function(req,res,result) {


res.render('welcome.ejs',{data: result});
});

app.get('/chat',function(req,res){
data.save(req.body,function(err)
{console.log('trying to save data');

data = response.write(JSON.stringify(req.body));

console.log(data);


if(err) throw err;
console.log('data saved');


});
res.redirect('/welcome');
});


app.listen(3000,function(err){
if(err) throw err;
})
```

views/welcome.ejs ---

```
<html>
<style>

h1 {
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 10px;
}
box {
background-color: lightblue;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 200px;
  }
</style>
 <head><h1> Welcome</h1></head>
 <body>
 <class= "box" >
 <% for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
 for(var j=0;j<data.name.length;j++){
 %>

    <%= data[i].name %>:<%=data.name[j].chat%>

    </class>
    <form class="form" method="post" action="/chat">
   <input type="text" placeholer="text" name="chatarea">
    <button type="submit">enter<"/button>
   </form>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Where is the error ? please provide the error here

Comment: Well `var i=0=;` **is** an invalid assignment

Comment: Btw, global `usern` and especially `userp` variables are a **horrible idea** in an asynchronous environment.

Comment: @Bergi now it says Unexpected token catch in views/welcome.ejs while compiling ejs

Comment: @bergi i know im just trying to laern the authentication in nodejs i have one database in mlab that im going to use for future

Comment: Where are you closing the loop blocks?!

Comment: @Bergi Thanks , I just did

Answer (score 0):

In your `.ejs` file:

```
<% for(var i=0=;i<data.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<data.name.length;j++){
%>
```

Change the `for(var i=0=;` to `for(var i=0;`

UPDATE, in your `.ejs` file you've added a double quote at the beggining of the `</button>` tag change this:

```
<input type="text" placeholer="text" name="chatarea">
    <button type="submit">enter<"/button>
</form>
```

To this:

```
<input type="text" placeholer="text" name="chatarea">
    <button type="submit">enter</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i've changed this and updated my question aswell, now the error is "Unexpected token catch in views/welcome.ejs while compiling ejs".Thanks for the efforts

Comment: am i saving the chatboxarea data in data[] array the right way?

Comment: ive updated my question aswell, thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the problem is solved, but the main problem is that you use the old var method and you should use the const method.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).